# What's your longest-lasting bug that you created or encountered?

Tags: language-agnostic

What's the bug that you inadvertently created or encountered that remained undiscovered for the longest period of time?

Comment: -1 what's the value and purpose of this question?

Comment: I think it's a fun question.  Definitely community wiki but I've got enjoyment out of similar questions elsewhere on SO.

Comment: There are many similar questions in the archives.

Comment: There is something wrong with stackoverflow.  this is a great question!

Comment: *"There is something wrong with stackoverflow."* No there is not. A lot of people seem to be trying to use SO as a substitute for SlashDot or other discussion sites. Well, the engine here is ill suited to it, and doing so distracted from the focus of the site which is to help people find answers to programming problems. This is an interesting question, but it is not material for SO.

Answer (score 2):

How about this vulnerability that was left unpatched for 17 years:
http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/17-year-old-unpatched-windows-vulnerability-discovered-20100120/

There was also the "drag-and-drop"  vulnerability that allowed for remote code execution in IE that was being exploited for many years before it was finely patched.  There is also the  "[Passing The Hash](http://www.cqure.net/wp/11/)"  SMB vulnerability that Microsoft ignored from ~2000-2007.  In both cases Microsoft denied that there was a vulnerability while hackers happy to pw3n the neglected windows boxen.

All three of these are now patched.

Answer (score 0):

Related:

- [The First Computer Bug!](http://www.waterholes.com/~dennette/1996/hopper/bug.htm)
- [History's Worst Software Bugs](http://www.wired.com/software/coolapps/news/2005/11/69355)
- [20 Famous Software Disasters](http://www.devtopics.com/20-famous-software-disasters/)